# which java version is compatible with grails groovy tool suite 3.5

Tags: grails, groovy

Iam new to grails groovy development .when i try to create grails project in ggts
i got this error

```
Command terminated with an exception: java.lang.Exception (see details for partial output)
Command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\javaw.exe (23-Dec-2015 11:59:06 am)
---- System.out ----
|Loading Grails 2.3.8
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
..........
|Compiling 78 source files
.Error 
|
Compilation error: startup failed:
F:\GrailsProjects\cvgrvt\target\work\plugins\database-migration-1.4.0\grails-app\controllers\grails\plugin\databasemigration\DbdocController.groovy: -1: Repetitive method name/signature for method 'java.lang.Object withFormat(groovy.lang.Closure)' in class 'grails.plugin.databasemigration.DbdocController'.
 @ line -1, column -1.
2 errors

---- System.err ----
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

------System.out:-----------
 |Loading Grails 2.3.8
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
..........
|Compiling 78 source files
.Error 
|
Compilation error: startup failed:
F:\GrailsProjects\cvgrvt\target\work\plugins\database-migration-1.4.0\grails-app\controllers\grails\plugin\databasemigration\DbdocController.groovy: -1: Repetitive method name/signature for method 'java.lang.Object withFormat(groovy.lang.Closure)' in class 'grails.plugin.databasemigration.DbdocController'.
 @ line -1, column -1.
2 errors

------System.err:-----------
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest upgrading to grails version 2.4.4

if you want to use version 2.3.x, switch to JDK 7